# Any way to detect android tv HDMI cable connected or not on expo react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, android-tv

im developping an android TV app with react native via expo. I need to know HDMI cable is connected or not. Thy for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Expo, I don't believe there is a way to detect this as of now.

https://forums.expo.io/t/rn-expo-build-for-android-tv/9403

Using React Native, you can use the following from the React Native documentation:

```
var Platform = require('Platform');
var running_on_android_tv = Platform.isTV;
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv

As to whether or not you can detect if they are using an HDMI cable specifically, I think you'd have to tap into the native code for that which would require you to eject.